# React beautiful DND: Detected non-consecutive <Draggable /> indexes - Error when re-reodering

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd after reordering some element for the first time, reordering of the previously moved item is not possible and the console prints

```
 Unable to find draggable with id: XXX
```

Also, when dragging another item the UI get broken and the console prints:

```
Detected non-consecutive <Draggable /> indexes.(This can cause unexpected bugs) 0, [2], 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You have to add the `key` property to the  `<Draggable key={uniqueId} ...>` component.

also, please notice:

- You cannot use the array `index` as value for the `key` attribute
- key value should be a unique id and stable value (not change across re-render) that represents the element

**BROKEN**

```
    <Draggable draggableId={id} index={index}>
                {(provided) => (
                   ...
                )}
    </Draggable>
```

**FIXED**

```
<Draggable key={uniqueId} draggableId={uniqueId} index={index}>
            {(provided) => (
                     ...
            )}
 </Draggable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error due to a bug in my state logic, where two draggables (in different droppables) had the same draggableId.